# Get current URL and trim with PHP

Tags: php

Im getting the URL using:

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

This returns something like:

http://me.domain.co.uk

How can I select 'me' only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$uriParts = explode('.',$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

$subDomain = $uriParts[0];
```

Comment: Note that $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] does not contain the host which was requested (HTTP Host header) which might not be what danit wants.

Answer (score 1):

Use [parse_url](http://de3.php.net/parse_url), get the host of the URL and split it by dots. Then you can retrieve your desired subdomain easily.

Edit: Answered too fast, this is not the *real* answer to your problem, you could do that this way but i wouldn't do it. If you want the *requested* subdomain you can use something like that:

```
$hostParts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
print $hostParts[0];
```

Note that this example does not include error handling. (i.e.: $_SERVER['`HTTP_HOST`'] might be empty)