# php script to get URL visited from browser via PHP

Tags: php

I want to write a simple php script to get URL visited from browser via PHP with:

```
  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

It should look something like this:

```
<?php
...some stuff to print out the variable...
?>
```

Comment: Do you mean the previous visited page?

Comment: `<?php print  $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>`

Comment: store in referer of xforward header, check out header types at wiki! ;>

Comment: No. I did mean the current page. I need to know, how my nginx performs page request behind another reverse proxy web-server.

Comment: And the answer is:   <?php print $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>   Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current URL and trim with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439601/get-current-url-and-trim-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose one or use some vars did you needed from $_SERVER vars:

```
foreach($_SERVER as $key => $value){
  echo '$_SERVER[\''. $key .'\'] => '. $value .'<br /><br />';
}
```

above will displaying all value. 
maybe you need create new db table with column ip and url_visited.